# I can't manage to import and use a javascript function from a .js into a django template. Ideas?

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have a javascript file `project_dashboard.js` with a few things defined inside of it and an html file where I try to call such function (amont other things).

For some reason, I keep getting the error that the function `is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick`. What drives me crazy is that the first part of the .js is loaded and works (the css is changed if I click on table). So the script is there, but I can't use the function.

**project_dashboard.js**

```
 $('table').on('click', 'tr.parent .fa-chevron-down', function(){
     $(this).closest('tbody').toggleClass('open');
 });

 function EnablePositionEdit(position_id) {
     const checked_events = []
     $("#edit_button_____" + position_id).toggle()
     $("#save_button_____" + position_id).toggle()
     $("#delete_____" + position_id).toggle()
     inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".availability_____" + position_id + " input")
     inputs.forEach(input => {
         input.removeAttribute("disabled")
     })

 }
```

**html**

```
{% extends 'action/base.html' %}
{% block extrastylesheets %}
{% endblock extrastylesheets %}
{% block content %}
<head>
  {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'action/css/project_dashboard.css' %}">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

...

<div id="edit_button_____{{ position.id }}" style="display: block;">
    <button class="btn" style="font-size:10px; color: rgb(59, 89, 152);" onclick = EnablePositionEdit('{{ position.id }}')> <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> </button>
</div>

...
{% endblock content %}
{% block extrascripts %}
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'action/js/project_dashboard.js' %}"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.summernotable').summernote({
            toolbar: [],
        });
    });
....
</script>
{% endblock extrascripts %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap the function name in quotes, as you do for all attributes, and place the script that contains the function before you call the function.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'action/js/project_dashboard.js' %}"></script>

<button class="btn" style="font-size:10px; color: rgb(59, 89, 152);" onclick = "EnablePositionEdit('{{ position.id }}')"> <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> </button>
```

Comment: It stills give me the same error unfortunately: ```Uncaught ReferenceError: EnablePositionEdit is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ```.

I wonder if it's an issue of how I defined the function on the other file? Maybe I should have some sort of export? or I should have an import in the html?

Comment: @giagi, No, you don't need to add anything, the function name will be found in the script. Just noticed another issue - you have placed the script after the onsubmit reference. Please place the script BEFORE you call the function.

Comment: I moved it to the head but still, same problem. And now also the part regarding $('table')...) doesn't work so I feel it's not the right spot on the head.